# Stream Binary File from Database / webserver? C#

Tags: c#

I've started to work on my runPE just to get a little more familiar with C# and how a runPE work. Just for learning purposes. 
And this is how I do it.

```
private static void Inject(string injectTo, string binToInject)
{
    int num = 0;
    RunPe.Run(Path.Combine(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), /*injectTo*/"ilasm.exe"),"", File.ReadAllBytes(binToInject), 4, ref num);
}
```

How ever, right now the bin(.exe) file I 'inject' located on my machine, what I would like to do is to stream this bin from DataBase or a server so it would not need to be on my machine. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this is the only interaction you have with the file?:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(binToInject)
```

[All that does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes) is return a `byte[]` array representing the contents of the file.  So anything which returns the same thing would work as a drop-in functional replacement.

Any data access technology (plain ADO.NET, Entity Framework, etc.) would generally treat a `BLOB` column (which would contain a file) as a `byte[]`, or at least something easily converted to that.  So in general, yes, you can serve your file from any source.

Comment: I'll look closer into that, thanks. And File.ReadAllBytes is the only interaction I have right now with the file, though I would not have a problem to change that if it would make the secound part easier.

Comment: Accepting this as an answear as thanks to this i got it working flawless. Thanks a ton.